# Create the summary table SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of product stock (`ProductStockTemp`):

```
ProductStockId | ProductCode | ProductName | ProductStockClosingBalance
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        |     A1      |     A2      |          200
      2        |     B1      |     B2      |          0
      3        |     A1      |     A2      |          100
      4        |     C1      |     C2      |         -400
      5        |     B1      |     B2      |          700
      6        |     C1      |     C2      |          0
      7        |     D1      |     D2      |          0
      8        |     D1      |     D2      |          0
```

I would like to create a table like that

```
ProductCode | ProductName | TypeA | TypeB
------------------------------------------
      A1    |     A2      |  200  |  100   
      B1    |     B2      |   0   |  700
      C1    |     C2      | -400  |   0   
      D1    |     D2      |   0   |   0
```

It means the first product record will be the product type A and the latest record will be the product type B. I think i have to select the latest product record first. However, the problem arises when the product appears one time then it will choose this record. In this case, I want the product type B will be 0 since the first will be the product type A and the latest will be the type B. My query to select the latest product record in the table

```
select 
    p.ProductCode, 
    p.ProductName, 
    p.ProductStockClosingBalance 
from 
    ProductStockTemp p 
where 
    p.ProductStockId = (select MAX(q.ProductStockId) 
                        from ProductStockTemp q 
                        where p.ProductCode = q.ProductCode) 
order by 
    p.ProductCode
```

I'm really stuck right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvius in my opinion for this case:

```
;with cteStock as
(
  select 
    p.ProductCode, 
    p.ProductName, 
    p.ProductStockClosingBalance,
    row_number() over(partition by p.ProductCode, p.ProductName order by p.ProductStockId asc) rn_asc,
    row_number() over(partition by p.ProductCode, p.ProductName order by p.ProductStockId desc) rn_desc,
  from ProductStockTemp p 
)
select 
  s.ProductCode, s.ProductName,
  sum(case when s.rn_asc = 1 then s.ProductStockClosingBalance else 0) as TypeA,
  sum(case when s.rn_desc = 1 and s.rn_asc != s.rn_desc then s.ProductStockClosingBalance else 0) as TypeB
from cteStock s
group by s.ProductCode, s.ProductName
```

but it's no good to have such a denormalized table with no info about period and names stored right here.

`s.rn_asc != s.rn_desc` - for the case when there is only one row.
Not sure about default zero but it's up to you and your task definition.

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
    ;With ctef as (select ProductCode , ProductName , ProductStockClosingBalance
                  row_number()over(partition  by ProductCode , ProductName ordered by ProductStockId  asc) as r  from ProductStock)
    ,  ctef1 as ( select * from  ctef where  r  =1)    
    , ctel as (select ProductCode , ProductName , ProductStockClosingBalance
                    row_number()over(partition  by ProductCode , ProductName ordered by ProductStockId  desc)as r2  from ProductStock )
    , ctel1 as ( select * from  ctel where  r  =1)       

    select f.ProductCode , f.ProductName ,f.ProductStockClosingBalance as typea ,nullif(l.ProductStockClosingBalance ,f.ProductStockClosingBalance ) as  typeB
    from ctef1  f left join  ctel1 s
       on f.ProductCode =s.ProductCode and f.ProductName =s.ProductName
```

if using sql servere 2012 or above Analytic Functions  [FIRST_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) and [LAST_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) can be used .

Comment: IFNULL ? Maybe NULLIF.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to learn SQL GROUP BY Statement

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName, min(ProductStockClosingBalance) as TypeA, Max(ProductStockClosingBalance) as TypeB 
FROM ProductStockTemp p 
GROUP BY ProductCode, ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

This query does what you want.

```
declare @prod table(ProductStockId int, ProductCode varchar(10), ProductName varchar(10), ProductStockClosingBalance int)
insert @prod values
(      1        ,     'A1'      ,     'A2'      ,          200),
(      2        ,     'B1'      ,     'B2'      ,          0),
(      3        ,     'A1'      ,     'A2'      ,          100),
(      4        ,     'C1'      ,     'C2'      ,         -400),
(      5        ,     'B1'      ,     'B2'      ,          700),
(      6        ,     'C1'      ,     'C2'      ,          0),
(      7        ,     'D1'      ,     'D2'      ,          0),
(      8        ,     'D1'      ,     'D2'      ,          0  )

;with prod as(
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by productcode order by ProductStockId) rn1
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by productcode order by ProductStockId desc) rn2
from @prod
)
select productcode,ProductName,
(select  ProductStockClosingBalance from prod p1 where p.productcode=p1.ProductCode and p1.rn1=1) TypeA,
ProductStockClosingBalance typeB
from prod p
where rn2=1
```

Results:

```
productcode ProductName TypeA   typeB
A1  A2  200 100
B1  B2  0   700
C1  C2  -400    0
D1  D2  0   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Mostly closed to my requirements